# Real timeyness in recharts?

Tags: recharts

Sorry if this is not appropriate question for SO: I want to open a socket and feed data to a simple line graph as real time as possible. maybe 4 refreshes per second? A lot of google searching and not much has turned up wrt how to handle this. is this possible with recharts? is it just a matter of making a custom refresh function?

Answer (score 1):

There is not just one answer to your question because there are a lot of ways of doing this. Right now I'm doing something similar, so I'll use that as an example:

1. SignalR connects to my server and re3ceives real-time updates.
2. Update is stored in Redux (you can use any other datastore).
3. Graph component is connected to the store.
4. When data is updated, graph changes.

In this case there is no refreshing limit, the bar updates the moment the data comes in. You don't need any sort of refreshing function. Hope this helps.